# NextJS gets 504 Gateway Timeout for subdomain

Tags: reactjs, next.js, digital-ocean, web-hosting

I have set up two deployments of the same NextJS codebase using Digital Ocean's App Platform. They use the same code, almost the same environment variables with the difference being the domain name and database name they connect to. However, the two servers behave quite differently and it seems like it has something to do with the domain name they're using. Server 1 is running on *https://example.com* and is working as expected while server 2 is running on *https://dev.example.com* and is getting a lot of error messages and struggling to serve the sites correctly.

The error messages I get is `504 Gateway Timeout` (and sometimes `524 No Reason Phrase` and `[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 7 of the JSON data`). I have run this setup before, but the issue seemed to appear once I started to use static site generation while getting data from a headless-cms (Sanity). I do not get any error messages on server 1.

The unexpected behavior I experience is for example the site returning 404 when i refresh a page (it *usually* loads as expected on first load, but not always), missing pictures from the headless cms and failure to load *some* paths that is generated by `getStaticPaths` while others load as expected. Interestingly I get the Digital Ocean 404 page when a path fails to load instead of the 404 page served by Next.

This is my implementation of getStaticProps and getStaticPaths.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {                                                                                                                                                             
  const paths = await sanity.fetch(`*[_type == "resources" && defined(slug.current)][].slug.current`);                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  return {                                                                                                                                                                                           
    paths: paths.map((slug: any) => ({ params: { slug } })),                                                                                                                                         
    fallback: true,                                                                                                                                                                                  
  };                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}


export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {                                                                                                                                                 
  const { slug = '' } = context.params;                                                                                                                                                              
  const resource = await sanity.fetch(                                                                                                                                                               
    groq`*[_type == "resources" && slug.current == $slug][0]`,                                                                                                                                           
    { slug }                                                                                                                                                                                         
  );                                                                                                                                                                                                 

  return {                                                                                                                                                                                           
    props: {                                                                                                                                                                                         
      resource,                                                                                                                                                                                      
    },                                                                                                                                                                                               
    revalidate: 600,                                                                                                                                                                                 
  };                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Server 1 has an alias for *https://www.example.com* and it used to have the same issues as server 2 when accessing the site from this alias. After I set up a redirect from *www* to non-www the issues disappeard. My redirect is setup usign middleware like this:

```js
 export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {                                                                                                                                                       
   const host = req.headers.get('host');                                                                                                                                                              
   const wwwRegex = /^www\./;                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   if (host !== null && wwwRegex.test(host) && !req.headers.get('host')?.includes('localhost')) {                                                                                                     
     const newHost = host.replace(wwwRegex, '');                                                                                                                                                      
     return NextResponse.redirect(`${host}/${req.nextUrl.pathname}?${req.nextUrl.searchParams}`, 308);                                                                                                
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   return NextResponse.next();                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

The build runs as expected when building on my local machine and accessing the site on *localhost:8080*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong and this had nothing to do with the subdomain. It turned out that both servers were faulty, it was just differences in the datasets that made them behave differently.

However, I solved the issue regardless. Turns out it was the images that created the 504 errors because i had not installed the package `sharp`. Sharp is required for image optimalization by NextJS and thus it created problems when it was not installed.

The answer was therefore `yarn add sharp`